# Receiving POST request data using Superagent and Express 4

Tags: node.js, post, express, router, superagent

Express -v : 4.13.3

Superagent -v : 1.4

function to send the POST request from the front-end of my app:

```
search: () => {
    request.post('/api/search')
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      .send({hello: 'hello w'})
      .end((err, response) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);

        serveractions.receiveTest(response);
      });
  }
```

my express router file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

router.post('/api/search', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.json({test: 'post received'});
});

module.exports = router;
```

The request is successfully being sent and received by the router, but req.body is always empty even though I am doing `.send({hello: 'hello w'})` with Superagent. What do I need to change in order to correctly send the json object and receive it in my router?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out the answer:

I changed my router file to:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

router.use( bodyParser.json() );
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

router.post('/api/search', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.json({test: 'post received'});
});

module.exports = router;
```

And my request method to:

```
searchRequest : (data) => {
  request
    .post('/api/search')
    .send({ searchTerm : data })
    .end((err, res) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      console.log(res);
    })
}
```